# Automatic recovery of ext4 filesystem

Tags: boot, mount, xubuntu, ext4, fsck

Last days I was facing problems with power outages/glitches that caused some failures on ext4 filesystem, the fs was then remounted as read-only. 
Unfortunately, this caused crash of few important services (bamboo agents) that need to write to that filesystem.

To fix this, I need to manually reboot the machine (and sometimes also run fsck from the initrd and go through all the errors).

I was wondering if there is any better (automatic) solution. Would adding `errors=panic` mount option to the fstab cause the system to reboot? The filesystem would then be fsck'ed automatically.

The machine is running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive seen this may times; especially on vmware.

As far as I know, errors=panic dos not acually work ( but try for yourself; it may be implmented now.. )
Panic also dont help you much, as system would still be down/dead...

If you change filesystem type to xfs:
Xfs is a bit different in handling write-errors - at least it dos not go readonly. There are still errors and I believe your application can get write errors on some files, until you reboot/unmount and run xfs_repair. 
- this can give a corrupted database...

The real solution is to have stable hardware (stable SAN/VMware... )..

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The machine is indeed running under VMware esxi. I am currently working on getting a new UPS which could mitigate those ripples during power outages.
I read a note from RH [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/xfs-error-behavior) on XFS error behavior and it looks it could also solve my problem.